# Continuous function between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $ (X,\tau_{X}) $ and $ (Y,\tau_{Y}) $ be topological spaces and $ f:X\rightarrow Y $ be a function. My question is how to show if for each $ A\subseteq Y $ , $\overline{f^{-1}(A)}$ $ \subseteq f^{-1}(\bar{A}) $  then f is continuous on X.

Comment: What characterisations of continuous functions are you familiar with?

Comment: Try showing the pre image of a closed set is closed. If $A$ is closed, then $\overline{f^{-1}(A)}\subset f^{-1}(\overline{A})$. But $A=\overline A$ so $f^{-1}(\overline A)= f^{-1}(A)$...

Comment: Thanks user54440.
$ f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(\bar{A})\supseteq \overline{f^{-1}(A)}$ then $ f^{-1}(A)$ is closed and hence f is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What does the condition tell you about $f^{-1}(F)$ for closed $F\subset Y$?